# Disable implicit conversion of quoted values to integer

Tags: postgresql

```
# CREATE TABLE foo ( id serial, val integer );
CREATE TABLE
# INSERT INTO foo (val) VALUES ('1'), (2);
INSERT 0 2
# SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id='1';
 id | val 
----+-----
  1 |   1
(1 row)
```

Here, both on insert and on selection postgres implicitly converts quoted strings to integral types rather than raise a type error, unless the quoted value is very specifically typed as a varchar:

```
# INSERT INTO foo (val) VALUES (varchar '1');
ERROR:  column "val" is of type integer 
        but expression is of type character varying
LINE 1: INSERT INTO foo (val) VALUES (varchar '1');
                                              ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

The issue here is for dynamically typed languages without implicit conversions (e.g. Ruby or Python)

- a quoted value maps to a string
- an integer maps to an integer
- those are not compatible so depending on the connecting application's architecture this behavior may lead to incoherent caches and the like

Is there a way to disable it and force quoted values to always be varchars (unless explicitly convert)?

edit: because people apparently focus on the irrelevant, these queries come from parameterized statements, psycopg2 will convert strings to quoted values and quoted values back to strings, so the mismatch exists regardless of access method, that's a red herring. here's the exact same thing with parameterised statements:

```
import psycopg2.extensions

with psycopg2.connect(dbname='postgres') as cn:
    cn.set_isolation_level(psycopg2.extensions.ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)
    with cn.cursor() as cx:
        cx.execute("DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS test")
        cx.execute("CREATE DATABASE test")

with psycopg2.connect(dbname='test') as cn:
    with cn.cursor() as cx:
        cx.execute("CREATE TABLE foo ( id serial, val integer )")
        cx.execute("INSERT INTO foo (val) VALUES (%s), (%s)",
                   (1, '2'))
        cx.execute("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id=%s",
                   ('1',))
        print cx.fetchall()
```

which outputs:

```
[(1, 1)]
```

Comment: So why do you use a character literal for a number in your SQL in the place?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name At a guess, SQL building http://bobby-tables.com/ style, with `INSERT INTO foo(val) VALUES (%s)` and client-side substitution...

Comment: You're both wrong, the queries here are examples but you get the same thing with parameterised statements (which are being used, all accesses are through psycopg2 in this case).

Comment: If there are quoted values in the SQL string, then the queries are *not* "parameterized". A parameterized query is sent having placeholders *to the server* and the parameters are sent with a different/second API call. It seems in your case "parameterized" means the client API is generating complete statements and then sending them un-parameterized (from a server point of view). `INSERT INTO foo (val) VALUES ('1'), (2);` does not contain any parameters, only value literals. `INSERT INTO foo (val) VALUES (?), (?);` would be a parameterized query

Comment: There are no values in the *original* SQL, the example is just that, an *example* with just the bare minimum to demonstrate the issue. I added a new example with parameterised statements showing that the exact same thing happens because that's the way postgres works, parameterised statements *are not relevant*.

Comment: Again: if your framework sends `INSERT INTO foo (val) VALUES ('1'), (2);` to the server, then the statements are ***not*** parameterised (from a Postgres point of view). Your framework might use parameters, but it doesn't use parameterised statements. And yes this **is** relevant here (I would actually call this a bug in that framework as it clearly generates invalid SQL).

Comment: It seems psycopg only emulates prepared statements http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries -- you can make sure of that by executing `"select text %s", ("foo",)`: you should get `ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1" LINE 1: select text $1`, but if that query can run, that means psycopg sends parameters with unknown literals.

Comment: @xmo Your clarification, which shows *actual code* that more closely models the real problem and isn't oversimplified, makes a lot more sense. It looks like psycopg2 is being a bit too clever for its own good here. (BTW, while I'm going to see if I can provide you with a better answer because the properly explained problem interests me, the tone of how you've been communicating tempts me to delete and walk away instead.)

Comment: @CraigRinger surely you can understand the frustration of using the "proper" access API and getting multiple repeated suggestions that you're a moron for not using the proper API?

Comment: @xmo When you've simplified it out of the question so nobody knows you are, sure it's frustrating, but you can't expect readers to psychically know what your code _really_ is when it's different to what you posted, either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot disable implicit conversion of quoted literals to any target type. PostgreSQL considers such literals to be of `unknown` type unless overridden by a cast or literal type-specifier, and will convert from `unknown` to any type. There is no cast from `unknown` to a type in `pg_cast`; it's implicit. So you can't drop it.

As far as I know, PostgreSQL is following the SQL spec by accepting quoted literals as integers.

To PostgreSQL's type engine, `1` is an `integer`, and `'1'` is an `unknown` that's type-inferred to an `integer` if passed to an `integer` function, operator, or field. You cannot disable type inference from `unknown` or force `unknown` to be treated as `text` without hacking the parser / query planner directly.

What you should be doing is using parameterised statements instead of substituting literals into SQL. You won't have this issue if you do so, because the client-side type is known or can be specified. That <del>certainly works with Python (psycopg2) and Ruby (Pg gem)</del> doesn't work how I thought for psycopg2, see below.

---

*Update* after question clarification: In the narrow case being described here, psycopg2's client-side parameterised statements, while correct, do not produce the result the original poster desires. Running the demo in the update shows that psycopg2 isn't using PostgreSQL's v3 bind/execute protocol, it's using the simple query protocol and doing parameter substitution locally. So while you're using parameterised statements in Python, you're not using parameterised statements in PostgreSQL. I was mistaken above in saying that parameterised statments in psycopg2 would resolve this issue.

The demo runs this SQL, from the PostgreSQL logs:

```
< 2014-07-07 18:17:24.450 WST >LOG:  statement: INSERT INTO foo (val) VALUES (1), ('2')
< 2014-07-07 18:17:24.451 WST >LOG:  statement: SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id='1'
```

Note the lack of placement parameters. They're substituted client-side.

So if you want `psycopg2` to be stricter, you'll have to adapt the client side framework.

`psycopg2` is extensible, so that should be pretty practical - you need to override the type handlers for `str`, `unicode` and `integer` (or, in Python3, `bytes`, `str` and `integer`) using `psycopg2.extras`, per [adapting new types](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/advanced.html#adapting-new-types). There's even an FAQ entry about overriding psycopg2's handling of `float` as an example: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/faq.html#faq-float

The naïve approach won't work though, because of infinite recursion:

```
def adapt_str_strict(thestr):
    return psycopg2.extensions.AsIs('TEXT ' + psycopg2.extensions.adapt(thestr))

psycopg2.extensions.register_adapter(str, adapt_str_strict)
```

so you need to bypass type adapter registration to call the original underlying adapter for `str`. This will, though it's ugly:

```
def adapt_str_strict(thestr):
    return psycopg2.extensions.AsIs('TEXT ' + str(psycopg2.extensions.QuotedString(thestr)))

psycopg2.extensions.register_adapter(str, adapt_str_strict)
```

Run your demo with that and you get:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: parameter $1 of type text cannot be coerced to the expected type integer
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

---

(BTW, using server-side `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE` won't work, because you'll just suffer the same typing issues when passing values to `EXECUTE` via `psycopg2`).

Comment: See edition, access method was removed to minimise demonstration, the real code does use parameterised statements, they're not relevant the problem exists regardless.

Comment: @xmo See edit. It isn't pretty, but it works. Up to you to find a cleaner way. It re-uses psycopg2's existing `text` escaping.